# My code should go 18 times faster but is only 5 times faster

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, multicore

I have tried to really understand this question I am going to ask now for a year. Trying to google it, read about multicore computing, parallel.foreach approach, ask questions about this. But never got a clear answer for what is going on. I always suspect no one truly knows and just guessing.

**The Question:**

**My computer has: 24 cores.

I have a function: calculationFunction()**

*It is possible to test this code*

**Now to the benchmark which is my BIG question:**
If I run calculationFunction() with 1 core. It takes 42 seconds
If I run calculationFunction() with 18 cores. It takes 11 seconds

Now is my question why doesn't it go faster than 11 seconds. If 1 core takes 42 seconds. Shouldn't 18 cores take: **42/18 = Around or close to 2.33 seconds?**

What is truly the problem here. Is there a bottleneck somewhere or doesn't actually 18 cores get involved in this process. Something is not right?

**IMPORTANT TO MENTION:**
I know from other exact same tests. I have opened 18 instances of the same application and split a work into 18 pieces and this did go exactly 18 times faster.

So is there something that restricts ONE instance of an application to NOT use all 18 cores that I assign in this code?

It is possible to test this code:

```
public void runThreads()
{
    //Change this variable to make tests
    int nrCores = 18; 

    List<List<String>> minusLIST2D = new List<List<String>>(); 
    List<List<String>> plusLIST2D = new List<List<String>>();                
    int nrloops = 3000000;
    nrloops = nrloops / nrCores;

    /*---------------------------------------------------------------*/
    var stopwath = new Stopwatch(); 
    stopwath.Start();
    Task[] tasks = new Task[nrCores];
    for (int i = 0; i < nrCores; i++)
    {
        //Add lists
        minusLIST2D.Add(new List<String>());
        plusLIST2D.Add(new List<String>());

        //Start Task
        int index = i;
        tasks[index] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => calculationFunction(nrloops, minusLIST2D[index], plusLIST2D[index]));
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks); //Wait for all Tasks to complete
    stopwath.Stop(); 
    MessageBox.Show("Elapsec secs: " + stopwath.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString());
}

public void calculationFunction(int nrloops, List<String> minusLIST, List<String> plusLIST)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");

    double num1 = 0; double num2 = 0; double num3 = 0; double number1 = 0; double number2 = 0; double number3 = 0; double thenum1 = 0; double thenum2 = 0; double thenum3 = 0;
    double NUM1 = 0; double NUM2 = 0; double NUM3 = 0; double NUMBER1 = 0; double NUMBER2 = 0; double NUMBER3 = 0; String str = ""; String num11 = ""; String num22 = ""; String num33 = "";
    String number11 = ""; String number22 = ""; String number33 = ""; double calc1 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nrloops; i++)
    {
        //Calculate both calc scenarios!
        num1 = 12.3; number1 = 13.3; thenum1 = 14.3;
        num2 = 12.3; number2 = 13.3; thenum2 = 14.3;
        num3 = 12.3; number3 = 13.3; thenum3 = 14.3;

        NUM1 = num1; NUM2 = num2; NUM3 = num3; NUMBER1 = number1; NUMBER2 = number2; NUMBER3 = number3;
        if (num1 <= 0 || number1 <= 0) { NUM1 = thenum1; NUMBER1 = thenum1; }
        if (num2 <= 0 || number2 <= 0) { NUM2 = thenum2; NUMBER2 = thenum2; }
        if (num3 <= 0 || number3 <= 0) { NUM3 = thenum3; NUMBER3 = thenum3; }
        if (NUM1 > 0 && NUM2 > 0 && NUM3 > 0 && NUMBER1 > 0 && NUMBER2 > 0 && NUMBER3 > 0)
        {
            str = ""; num11 = ""; num22 = ""; num33 = ""; number11 = ""; number22 = ""; number33 = "";
            if (num1 > 0 && num2 > 0 && num3 > 0 && number1 > 0 && number2 > 0 && number3 > 0) { } 
            else { str = string.Format("{0:F10}", thenum1) + " / " + string.Format("{0:F10}", thenum2) + " / " + string.Format("{0:F10}", thenum3); }

            if (num1 <= 0) { num11 = "0"; num1 = thenum1; } else { num11 = string.Format("{0:F10}", num1); }
            if (num2 <= 0) { num22 = "0"; num2 = thenum2; } else { num22 = string.Format("{0:F10}", num2); }
            if (num3 <= 0) { num33 = "0"; num3 = thenum3; } else { num33 = string.Format("{0:F10}", num3); }
            if (number1 <= 0) { number11 = "0"; number1 = thenum1; } else { number11 = string.Format("{0:F10}", number1); }
            if (number2 <= 0) { number22 = "0"; number2 = thenum2; } else { number22 = string.Format("{0:F10}", number2); }
            if (number3 <= 0) { number33 = "0"; number3 = thenum3; } else { number33 = string.Format("{0:F10}", number3); }

            //Calculate
            calc1 = ((num1 * number2 * number3) - 45) / 10;

            //String
            str = calc1 + "," + "ab" + " - " + "ab" + " - " + "ab" + "," +
                  "ab" + " - " + "ab" + " - " + "ab" + "," +
                  num11 + " / " + num22 + " / " + num33 + "," +
                  number11 + " / " + number22 + " / " + number33 + "," +
                  str + "," +
                  calc1 + "%";

            if (calc1 > 0)
            {
                plusLIST.Add(str);
            }
            else
            {
                minusLIST.Add(str);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189293/discussion-on-question-by-andreas-my-code-should-go-18-times-faster-but-is-only).

Answer (score 3):

> I always suspect no one truly knows and just guessing.

Well, there are engineers who dedicate their whole careers studying and designing parallel systems. I suggest you think again.

Even with basic academic knowledge in the domain I can tell you a few things.

> If 1 core takes 60 seconds. Shouldn't 18 cores take: 60/18 = Around
>   or close to 3.33 seconds?

No, usually not. The (class of) problems that can be parallelized with this kind of efficiency are very rare. And even for those problems implementing this level efficiency is not a trivial task.

First there is the Amdahl's Law. Every problem has a serial portion (that cannot be parallelized) and a parallel portion. For example if only 90% of the problem can be parallelized Amdahl's Law says the maximum theoretical speedup you can achieve is 10x. Take a time to think about the implications. You can have 10, 100, 1'000'000 or an infinite amount of processors. You can never achieve more than 10x speedup for a problem that is 90% parallelizable.

And that is just a theoretical limit, assuming perfect parallelization with zero overhead.

In reality, threads and processes need time to initialize (which is time you don't have in the serial version). Threads need to be synchronized so they will spend some time just waiting for other threads. And any form of communication between them has an overhead. In reality the speedup is much worse then the theoretical limit given by Amdahl's Law.

Comment: I see, I had some knowledge about this also from before. But can it then really be that synchronized between thread, overheads, waiting for threads can be the reason for this. I still then wonder what is the difference with 18 instances for example that I know do a work 18 times faster. Are there "resources" assigned to different applications somehow which make the independent of eachother?